# Should it be was "completed" or "completed"? which one is correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-difference

> The antidepressants that I was prescribed were giving me vertigo attacks.
>   So I decided to stay at home until my course was completed

Answer (score -1):

Medics have created a course of antidepressants, and now it is complete  .

You went through the course  of antidepressants, and now it is completed .

Comment: And how does it answer the question?